Test Data Accuracy in Garden FI
While pulling transaction data from the Consumer API (Garden FI), it appears that the activity is not a representative example of the different types of transactions described in the Type and SubType sections of the Transaction Details API Documentation. Basically, every draft is a Type of "Transfer" and SubType is  "EFT" even when the transaction MEMO would suggest that it was a POS type of purchase. Is this just the nature of how test transaction data is populated in the sandbox or is this what we would see with a live FI? For example, is it safe to assume that a POS purchase with a debit card would be categorized as Type: POS and Subtype: PinDebit or are those not concrete rules?

In general, transactions are a bit of a messy concept - not just in the Garden test environment, but also with live banks and credit unions, if they make use of various customizations available at the core level.
This is largely why solutions for transaction enrichments are so widely used.
So it's not a bug or issue with Garden, it's just the way it's configured.
